UV Stretching unfounded
I am using version 4.2 and I don't know where to go to show the stretching in the UV editor.  I already pressed N and clicked on View and there is no indication of where it is.  All I could find in the UV menu is "Minimize Stretch".  I just need to see the stretching.
What should I click or press to show it?

If you open the Show Overlays dropdown you will see about halfway down an area marked UV Stretch.
You can turn it on or off with the checkbox:


